# Automatic Signing Fails with New App

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

Had to make a first release of a new app. Went and made the App ID and then generated an archive. On attempting to upload, it failed, saying that there were things in the provision that did not match the capabilities. Read a lot of threads about not being able to turn off Game Center or In App Purchases. Eventually the other dev on my team got the build to go, using auto. Mine did not. Same settings, same project files. Eventually I read the message more closely and it said turn off auto and fix. So I turned off auto and then was asked to assign a cert to sign with and there was one for my app. Picked it and it worked. After that, I tried to go back to auto. Failed again with the same error. Question is how do I get back to auto?

(Absolutely horrible experience...)

Comment: You work for team, so your team has git or what else that management your team's source code?

Comment: Yes we have git?

Comment: Just pull the newest code from server git and retry it

Comment: If the problem is solved my manual signing, use manual signing.

Comment: @QuocNguyen of course I did that..